# Change number format in dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I would like to change the number format of the index of a dataframe.
From the screenshot below `Paper ID` is all in e+07 format (I don't know how to call this btw) and I would like to change them into normal number such as 1147687 instead of 1.147687e+07.

Here's my dataframe:

[image: teamsize dataframe]

Comment: That’s [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). Using floats in your index seems dangerous as hell, can you provide some context here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your indexes values to `int`, but you must do it carefully, cause you can loose some ids:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PaperId':[1000000000.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], 
                      'memberNum':[1, 2, 3, 4]})

df = df.set_index('PaperId')
df
```

```
            memberNum
PaperId 
1.000000e+09    1
2.000000e+00    2
3.000000e+00    3
4.000000e+00    4
```

```
df['PaperId'] = df.index
df['PaperId'] = df['PaperId'].astype('int')
df = df.set_index('PaperId')
df
```

```
        memberNum
PaperId 
1000000000  1
2           2
3           3
4           4
```